# Erasing Element From a Vector Erases Multiple (C++)

Tags: c++, vector

I've been building a small Roguelike ASCII game that uses the console to build my limited knowledge of C++. I have it set up so when the player object's coordinates are the same as an item(which is stored in a vector), it removes the item and adds 10 to the player's HP.

The program starts out with 9 items in the room. BUT, whenever I get the item, it deletes the first 5 items in the vector(But they're still being drawn on the screen for some reason), and adds 50 to the health. So I'm left with 4 items. The next time I get an item, it removes the first 2 and adds 20 to the health. Now I'm left with 2 items. The last two times, it removes one item at a time.

So, essentially, the vector is being split in half each time I get an item. I've narrowed down the problem through a lot of debugging, and I'm pretty sure it's coming from this chunk of code:

```
for(int i=0;i<ia.size();i++) //If the player touches an item
{
        if(grid[p.getY()][p.getX()]==itm)
        {
            hp+=10;
            cout << "Item "<<i<<" removed\n";
            swap(ia[i], ia.back());
            ia.pop_back();
            system("pause");
        }
}
```

I'm still trying to figure out vectors, so if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Use std::vector::erase?

Comment: Perhaps a `break;` inside the `if(...)` would help...

Comment: I did try vector::erase as well, but nothing changed.

Comment: Your comparison is probably wrong: `itm` isnt related to your vector/iteration in anyway, so I guess the if block gets executed on every iteration. Without more information however, its impossible to tell. Also notice that you can replace `swap(...); ia.pop_back();` with `ia.erase(i);`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector for reference.

Comment: @abiessu Wow, thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of that. It seems obvious now. Thanks a bunch!

(I'm still dumbfounded as to how it was cut in half...)

Comment: Besides this: If you working with vectors or collections in general: Iteration with Iterators is prefered over iteration with index. If your using c++11, for-each is even better.

Comment: Please use !Paranaix's comments for guidance here, the `break;` is just a way to make sure you stop at the right point, but there are other issues here...

Comment: @Paranaix Why are iterators preferred?

Comment: Because there are collections which dont support random access (or atleast have a much higher complexity than std::vector, e.g std::linked_list). Iterators provide an abstraction for iterations and are thus genericly useable. Therefor vectors should be used for conformity and consistency.

Answer (score 1):

There're comments suggesting `erase()`, but be aware that it will copy later array elements one by one to fill in the index being vacated: your swap approach may be massively faster and is better if you don't care about element order.

One issue is that you swap the `back()` element into the position occupied by the element you're removing, then increment the iterator to test the next `ia` index.  This means that the items copied from the `back()` are never themselves tested - for that you want to avoid the `i++` after doing a `swap`.  Of course if only one item can ever occupy a grid position, you can just `break` as abiessu commented....

Here's some code that works as I think you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> ia{ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 };
    for(size_t i=0;i<ia.size(); ) //If the player touches an item
    {
        if(ia[i] % 20)
        {
            cout << "Item "<<i<<" removed\n";
            swap(ia[i], ia.back());
            ia.pop_back();
            continue;
        }
        else
            ++i;
}
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ia.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << '[' << i << "] " << ia[i] << '\n';
}
```

See it at http://ideone.com/JJ6CE6

That said, for some data types `ia[i] = ia.back();` will be faster than `swap` - for others slower (if they use and benefit from C++11 style "move").  You may also want to skip any self-swap/assignment if `i == size() - 1` (at least check that the array element type supports that safely).

Comment: Speed is completely meaningless here and prefering swap in this situation would be a perfect example for premature optimization IMHO if I have another option to select which is better in terms of code readability.

Comment: @Paranaix: you're welcome to your opinion of course, but O(N^2) vs O(N) is not "completely meaningless" in mine: at the very least it's something you should be aware of as you're writing the code, regardless of whether it influences your choice.